# If you use Two-For-One and destroy Rainbow Aura, can you also destroy a Unicorn card?

Tags: unstable-unicorns

My friend and I were playing Unstable Unicorns this morning, and she had the upgrade card Rainbow Aura in her stable. Rainbow Aura says:

> Your Unicorn cards cannot be destroyed.

I wanted to use the magic card Two-For-One, which allows you to:

> SACRIFICE a card, then DESTROY 2 cards.

I chose Rainbow Aura to destroy, which was fine, but we disagreed on whether I could destroy one of her unicorns as well. I said that because I destroyed Rainbow Aura first, I could destroy one of her unicorns as the second card. She said I would have to pick a card that wasn’t a unicorn in her stable to destroy, because they were destroyed at the same time.

Who is right, and can I destroy her unicorn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you cannot. The effect is "DESTROY 2" rather than "DESTROY 1 and then DESTROY 1". The two destructions are simultaneous and the Rainbow Aura prevents you from destroying the unicorn.

[Glossary](http://unstablegameswiki.com/index.php?title=UU_Game_Terminology_-_Destroy):

> Each destroy is a (destroy) effect that is performed as a single event up to the required number (which could be All). The required cards to be destroyed is determined simultaneously. You cannot choose the same Target for a destroy effect twice with the same destroy effect.

A [no-longer-existing FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1937563/two-one-vs-rainbow-aura) seems to have confirmed this case:

> As with beginning-of-turn effects, a card’s effect happens all at once. While you can get rid of their Upgrade card, the change to their Stable will not apply until after your whole card has been resolved. Think of it like two missiles being launched at the same time. Just because one takes out a target doesn’t mean the other one can change trajectory and Destroy something that it couldn’t Destroy when it was launched!

[This thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2388095/timing-two-one) agrees:

> I believe the destructions happen simultaneously as part of a single effect (you don't choose the order). Thus at the time of selecting the targets, you could not target the unicorn since the upgrade is still in play.